# how to use python-numpy-broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a trouble with python broadcasting

there is two numpy list

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

y = np.array([0,1,1])
```

I'd like to calculate

```
x : [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6]]
```

to

```
x : [[1-y[0], 2-y[1], 3-y[2]],
     [4-y[0], 5-y[1], 6-y[2]]]
```

that is,

```
x : [[0,-3,-3],
     [3,0,0]]
```

at one time.

Please, let me know how to do that.

I'm sorry...i had a mistake....

i mean 
    x : [[1,1,2],
         [4,4,5]]

Comment: check your math dude! a usual prerequisite for programming is to be able to do integer subtraction...

Comment: [[1-0, 2-1,  3-1],[4-0, 5-1, 6-1]] == [[0, -3, -3], [3, 0, 0]] ???

Comment: What does `x-y` produce?

Comment: @hpaulj: a male, I believe :)

Comment: Not able to subtract without mistakes ...

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. But, I want to calculate with no loop.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how you got:

```
x : [[0,-3,-3],
     [3,0,0]]
```

But the easiest way to do what you ask for is just:

```
import numpy as np
X = ([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
y = np.array([0,1,1])
print X-y
```

Output:

> [ [1 1 2]
>    [4 4 5] ]

Comment: Why are you iterating?  Just do `X-y` and get a 2d array.  Since `y` is an array, it treats `X` as one as well.

Comment: Thanks. it's very easy.